# Difficulty performing silence removal with librosa.effects.trim command

Tags: python, audio, librosa

I am trying to do a project, and in part of the project I have the user say a word which gets recorded. This word then gets the silence around it cut out, and there is a button that plays back their word without the silence. I am using librosa's `librosa.effects.trim` command to achieve this.

For example:

```
def record_audio():
    global myrecording
    global yt
    playsound(beep1)
    myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=1)
    sd.wait() 
    playsound(beep2)

    #trimming the audio
    yt, index = librosa.effects.trim(myrecording, top_db=60)
```

However, when I play the audio back, I can tell that it is not trimming the recording. The variable explorer shows that `myrecording` and `yt` are the same length. I can hear it when I play what is supposed to be the trimmed audio clip back as well. I don't get any error messages when this occurs either. Is there any way to get librosa to actually clip the audio? I have tried adjusting `top_db` and that did not fix it. Aside from that, I am not quite sure what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

For a real answer, you'd have to post a sample recording so that we could inspect what exactly is going on.

In lieu of of that, I'd like to refer to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/722), where one of the main authors of librosa offers advice for a very similar issue.

In essence: You want to lower the `top_db` threshold and reduce `frame_length` and `hop_length`. E.g.:

```
yt, index = librosa.effects.trim(myrecording, top_db=50, frame_length=256, hop_length=64)
```

Decreasing `hop_length` effectively increases the resolution for trimming. Decreasing `top_db` makes the function less sensitive, i.e., low level noise is also regarded as silence. Using a computer microphone, you do probably have quite a bit of low level background noise.

If this all does not help, you might want to consider using SOX, or its Python wrapper [pysox](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox). It also has a trim function.

**Update** Look at the waveform of your audio. Does it have a spike somewhere at the beginning? Some crack sound perhaps. That will keep librosa from trimming correctly. Perhaps manually throwing away the first second (`=fs` samples) and then trimming solves the issue:

```
librosa.effects.trim(myrecording[fs:], top_db=50, frame_length=256, hop_length=64)
```

Comment: This solution is closer to what I am looking for, but still does not quite solve it. The first one did not trim. The second one gave better results, but that was mainly because I had learned where the one second mark was a knew when to speak then, which the user would not know. I will try pysox and see how that works

Comment: Now that I think about it, it may be that the fans on my computer are too loud and that could be interfering with the trimming

Comment: There may also be a spike at the end preventing trailing silence removal. This is usually a percussive peak caused by the microphone detecting a button press to stop recording. This depends on what the recording device is, but it is something I have encountered.